# Can I declare named async tuple functions in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tuples

C# 7 allows us to declare functions that return named tuples, so a declaration like the one illustrated below is now ok.

```
(int quotient, int remainder) = GetDivisionResults(17, 5);
```

I have need to process the response from an HTTP Client request and extract two values from it, and I want to do so asynchronously. The following is allowed

```
public static async Task<<Tuple<string,string>> GetRequiredReturnValuesFromResponse(string response)
```

My simple question is, is it possible to name the output strings in the same way that I could were the function to operate synchronously along the lines as illustrated below?

```
public static async Task<Tuple< string OrderNumber,string OriginalId>> GetRequiredReturnValuesFromResponse(string response)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't name `Tuple` elements - only `ValueTuple` elements. C# 7 tuple support is based on the `ValueTuple` type. But even then, the names aren't part of `ValueTuple` itself... they're stored in attributes alongside the return type (or parameter type).

So you can definitely declare this:

```
public static async Task<(string OrderNumber, string OriginalId)>
    GetRequiredReturnValuesFromResponse(string response)
```

You can then use:

```
var tuple = await GetRequiredReturnValuesFromResponse(response);
Console.WriteLine(tuple.OrderNumber);
Console.WriteLine(tuple.OriginalId);
```

Or even:

```
var (number, id) = await GetRequiredReturnValuesFromResponse(response);
```

But you can't name the elements when explicitly using `ValueTuple` (unless you specify the naming attributes explicitly, which I believe the compiler warns you against anyway) or using `Tuple` at all.

Personally I'd recommend against putting `ValueTuple` types in *public* APIs; I typically regard them as a stop-gap measure for an internal implementation which I might decide to migrate to a more fully-encapsulated type later on. But that's just a personal opinion, and doesn't represent what you *can* do.

Comment: Thank you so much, a great explanation